# How should I temporarily store rows in a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, temp-tables

In essence I'd like to store some rows in a temporary variable for the life of a procedure in MySQL.

My procedure will grab a column of foreign keys at the beginning of the procedure. Once I'm done working with them I want to update the table to indicate that they have been processed. There may be inserts into this table while my procedure is working on it's set of data so I don't want to erroneously mark these new rows as processed. I also do not want to lock this table and hold up the thread that is making the inserts.

Is a temporary table the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporary table will be the easiest and probably the best way to go for this problem.

Comment: Yea, this what ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

If it's in SQL Server, investigate using a table variable instead...

```
Declare @MyFKs  Table 
   (FkId Integer Primary Key Not Null,
    isProcessed bit)
```

Although they are not as flexible (Can't add multiple indices to them),  Table variables do not participate in transaction logging like a temp table does, so, for narrow tables, where you are just storing a key and at most a few data columns, they can be better perfomance than a temp table.

Comment: ahh... sorry, then answer is yes, use temp tables.. but if it will manage more than a few thousand rows, make sure you put appropriate index(indices) on the temp table when you create it...